# Problemas con systemd - Unit puma.service could not be found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor, xubuntu

Quiero que un servicio se levante automáticamente cuando se reinicie el servidor, pero no lo logro, lo instalé, lo configuré, lo inicié y todo bien , pero al reiniciar la maquina, me sale el error del titulo de esta pregunta.

Mi Sistema operativo es un lubuntu 18.04.01

***Explico el detalle:***

Creé un servicio *puma.service* en la carpeta personal */home/usuario1/servicios*, adjunto el código:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
# Foreground process (do not use --daemon in ExecStart or config.rb)
Type=simple

User=usuario1

# Specify the path to your puma application root
WorkingDirectory=/home/usuario1/sites/proyecto1

ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc '/home/usuario1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/puma -C /home/usuario1/sites/proyecto1/config/puma.rb' 

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Creé un enlace para llamar a ese archivo:

```
 $ sudo ln -s /home/usuario1/servicios/puma.service /etc/systemd/system
```

Ejecuté el script:

```
 $ sudo systemctl enable puma.service
```

(me pidió la contraseña de root, OK)

Levanté el servicio con el script:

```
$ sudo systemctl start puma.service
```

Se levantó OK:

```
 $ sudo systemctl status puma.service
● puma.service - Puma HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/home/usuario1/servicios/puma.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-01-16 17:11:09 -04; 9s ago
 Main PID: 3557 (ruby)
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 4680)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puma.service
           ├─3557 puma 3.12.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000,unix:///home/usuario1/sites/proyecto1/shared/sockets/puma.sock) [proyecto1]
           ├─3734 puma: cluster worker 0: 3557 [proyecto1]
           ├─3738 puma: cluster worker 1: 3557 [proyecto1]
           ├─3742 puma: cluster worker 2: 3557 [proyecto1]
           └─3745 puma: cluster worker 3: 3557 [proyecto1]

ene 16 17:11:09 servidor1 systemd[1]: Started Puma HTTP Server.
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] Puma starting in cluster mode...
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] * Environment: production
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] * Process workers: 4
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] * Phased restart available
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] * Listening on unix:///home/usuario1/sites/proyecto1/shared/sockets/puma.sock
ene 16 17:11:17 servidor1 bash[3557]: [3557] Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Al reiniciar el servidor y escribir el comando en la consola para verificar que se esté ejecutando correctamente:

```
 $ sudo systemctl status puma.service
```

Me sale este mensaje...

**Unit puma.service could not be found.**

Tengo que hacer de nuevo todo el procedimiento desde `enable` el servicio para poder ver su `status` y levantarlo con `start` para que se levante el demonio Manualmente!!!. Y yo quiero que al reiniciar el servidor se inicie el demonio autimaticamente.

Alguna idea que pueda ser????

Comment: Me gustaría darte la respuesta, sin embargo podrías adaptar el material de aquí: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples y con ello puedas responder, y aceptar la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al aporte del usuario [fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) y la lectura muy detallada del enlace que me indicó el problema que tenía era que es **obligatorio** tener el archivo del servicio creado en la carpeta `/lib/systemd/system/puma.service` para que el SO lo pueda reconocer como un servicio a tener en cuenta en el próximo reboot.